# If or Case with Mustache

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm struggling with taking the data {{State}} which is the verbose US state name, "Georgia", for example, and return "GA" for us in the postal address.   Since Mustache is logic-less, I'm stumped.

UPDATE:
I think I need to use java script to do this but I'm at a loss using javascript with Mustache to pass in {{State}}, go through a switch statement and return the switch output to mustache.
What I have so far is:

```js
<label> State Abbreviation: </label><span id='stateabb'></span>
<script type = "text/javascript">

var BillTo =[
{{#Invoice.Account.BillTo}}
{
"state":"{{State}}"
},
{{/Invoice.Account.BillTo}}
];
            switch(state) {
               case 'New York';
                var stateabb = 'NY'
               break;
              default:'asfasfd'
            }
document.getElementById('stateabb').innerText = state;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In context of the mustache engine I'm using (Zuora), I was able put this together and it works.  The basis is the statement:

boolean ? true : false

```js
{{#Wp_Eval}}
"{{State}}" == "Alabama" ? "AL":
"({{State}}" == "Alaska" ? "AK":
"{{State}}" == "Arizona" ? "AZ":
"{{State}}" == "Arkansas" ? "AR":
"{{State}}" == "California" ? "CA":
"{{State}}" == "Colorado" ? "CO":
"{{State}}" == "Connecticut" ? "CT":
"{{State}}" == "Delaware" ? "DE":
"{{State}}" == "District of Columbia" ? "DC":
"{{State}}" == "Florida" ? "FL":
"{{State}}" == "Georgia" ? "GA":
"{{State}}" == "Hawaii" ? "HI":
"{{State}}" == "Idaho" ? "ID":
"{{State}}" == "Illinois" ? "IL":
"{{State}}" == "Indiana" ? "IN":
"{{State}}" == "Iowa" ? "IA":
"{{State}}" == "Kansas" ? "KS":
"{{State}}" == "Kentucky" ? "KY":
"{{State}}" == "Louisiana" ? "LA":
"{{State}}" == "Maine" ? "ME":
"{{State}}" == "Maryland" ? "MD":
"{{State}}" == "Massachusetts" ? "MA":
"{{State}}" == "Michigan" ? "MI":
"{{State}}" == "Minnesota" ? "MN":
"{{State}}" == "Mississippi" ? "MS":
"{{State}}" == "Missouri" ? "MO":
"{{State}}" == "Montana" ? "MT":
"{{State}}" == "Nebraska" ? "NE":
"{{State}}" == "Nevada" ? "NV":
"{{State}}" == "New Hampshire" ? "NH":
"{{State}}" == "New Jersey" ? "NJ":
"{{State}}" == "New Mexico" ? "NM":
"{{State}}" == "New York" ? "NY":
"{{State}}" == "North Carolina" ? "NC":
"{{State}}" == "North Dakota" ? "ND":
"{{State}}" == "Ohio" ? "OH":
"{{State}}" == "Oklahoma" ? "OK":
"{{State}}" == "Oregon" ? "OR":
"{{State}}" == "Pennsylvania" ? "PA":
"{{State}}" == "Rhode Island" ? "RI":
"{{State}}" == "South Carolina" ? "SC":
"{{State}}" == "South Dakota" ? "SD":
"{{State}}" == "Tennessee" ? "TN":
"{{State}}" == "Texas" ? "TX":
"{{State}}" == "Utah" ? "UT":
"{{State}}" == "Vermont" ? "VT":
"{{State}}" == "Virginia" ? "VA":
"{{State}}" == "Washington" ? "WA":
"{{State}}" == "West Virginia" ? "WV":
"{{State}}" == "Wisconsin" ? "WI":
"{{State}}" == "Wyoming" ? "WY":
"{{State}}" == "American Samoa" ? "AS":
"{{State}}" == "Guam" ? "GU":
"{{State}}" == "Northern Mariana Islands" ? "MP":
"{{State}}" == "Puerto Rico" ? "PR":
"{{State}}" == "U.S. Virgin Islands" ? "VI":
"{{State}}" == "U.S. Minor Outlying Islands" ? "UM":""
{{/Wp_Eval}}
```